# Pass a class "self" for other classes' instances?

Tags: python

From an existing code, I need to create instance from a class within another class while lots of information that are needed for initializing the called class, are contained in the caller one.

A way to pass some attributes of a caller class to the called class can be like in the following example passing `self` as argument and it does what exactly is expected, bu I wondered if it is the correct or whether is there a better way to do so?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 10
        self.myObj = B(self)

class B:
    def __init__(self, Obj_from_A):
        self.i = None
        self.j = None
        self.v= Obj_from_A.x
        self.w = Obj_from_A.y

A_obj = A()
print(A_obj.myObj.v, A_obj.myObj.w)
```

Output:

```
1 10
```

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong with this. Are sure that you need to store `v` and `w` separately, instead of just holding on to a reference to `Obj_from_A` itself? (That does create a reference cycle, but the garbage collection can handle that.)

Comment: Passing `self` is a perfectly reasonable and idiomatic way to give some other object a reference to this object. Of course you could rewrite this so that `B.__init__(self, v, w)` and then `self.myObj = B(self.x, self.y)`, but either one is fine; it's just a matter of whether it feels "more natural" for `B` to take "something with `x` and `y` attributes" (or "specifically an A"), or for it to take "a pair of coordinates"—which is impossible to judge from this toy model, but should be obvious in most real code.

Comment: Thanks @chepner for your reply. I think yes, because I'm trying to keep the original (real) codes as intact as possible, but I see your point is more reasonable.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert for your answer, it clarified me now.

Comment: It's also worth considering that because `self.myObj = B(self)` is the way to intentionally create a reference cycle (which, as @chepner says, is fine—I'm pretty sure there are examples of exactly that idiom in the stdlib), a reader of the code for `A` (who didn't see the code for `B`) might _think_ you were intending that here. If that could be misleading, that might be a different reason to pass `self.x, self.y` instead. On the other hand, if that isn't misleading, and might even be something you could end up doing in v2.0, it might be a reason to pass `self`.

Comment: Ask yourself if you are *linking* an instance of `A` to an instance of `B`, or *initializing* an instance of `B` with an instance of `A`. Whichever it is, add a comment to that effect.

Comment: Exactly, initializing an instance of `B` with an instance of `A`.

Comment: @chepner; I got your point, actually your are right and I do so, here wrote like this to make my question clear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class does what you think it is doing, except when it might not.

(btw your code does not run: you don't define `B_Obj`)

See the extra code I've added at the end:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 10
        self.myObj = B(self)

class B:
    def __init__(self, Obj_from_A):
        self.i = 0
        self.j = 0
        self.v= Obj_from_A.x
        self.w = Obj_from_A.y

A_obj = A()
print(A_obj.myObj.v, A_obj.myObj.w)

A_obj.x = 2  # Now update the x member
print(A_obj.x, A_obj.myObj.v, A_obj.myObj.w)
```

Output:

```
1 10
2 1 10
```

Here `A_obj.x` has changed, but the instance of `B` has held onto the previous values.